# Cucumber Java: Does not recognize a Long data type

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying to create a cucumber test for a REST endpoint in Java.  The cucumber version I am using is: 3.0.2.

It is a a GET Request and takes 1 parameter that is of type, Long.
I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Could
>   not create a cucumber expression for 'parameter carrierTender {Long}'.
>   It appears you did not register parameter type.

The Feature file is as follows:

```
  Scenario Outline: Get the purchase tender data for a given carrier tender id
    Given  parameter carrierTender <carrier_tender_id>
    When the Purchased Service requests purchase tender data
    Then the result has a return Code <return_code>
    And a purchase tender record is returned

    Examples:
      | carrier_tender_id | return_code |
      | 12345678          | 200         |
```

The Step Definitions are as follows:

```
 @Given( "parameter carrierTender {Long}")
    public void parameterCarrierTenderCarrierTenderId(Long arg0) {

        carrierTenderId = arg0;
    }

    @When("the Purchased Service requests purchase tender data")
    public void purchasedServiceRequestsPurchaseTenderData() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
      //   String purchaseTenderPathValue = "purchaseTender/" + Long.valueOf(carrierTenderId);
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(getRequest.getURI() + "purchaseTender")
                .setParameter("carrierTenderId", String.valueOf(carrierTenderId));

        LOGGER.info("URL Request: {}", uriBuilder.getPath());
        getRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        getRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        getRequest.setURI(uriBuilder.build());

        getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        LOGGER.info("Response: {}", getResponse.toString());
    }

   @Then("the result has a returnCode {int}")
    public void onSuccessfulResultTheResultHasAReturnCode(int arg0) {
        assertEquals(arg0, getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    @And("a purchase tender record is returned")
    public void purchaseTenderRecordReturned() {
        assertNotNull(getResponse.getEntity());
    }
```

Does Cucumber not recognize the Long Data type?  In the cucumber documentation it says it does so I am not sure if it is the data type or something else.

Answer (score 4):

This is silly....I changed the data type from a `Long` to a `long` and it was recognized.

Comment: same story  with String -> string

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing as Gloria Santin and within the method I used Long.ValueOf(long from parameter).
Worked for me.